# Specific format for printing from CSS

Tags: css, printing

I have to print something and it's got to be pretty specific.

Now, I've gone as far as I can, but what I want to know is how to make a table fit within the margins specified.

```
/* ===== Printing ===== */
@media print {
    /*Reset Style*/
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    /*Remove Element*/
    .main, .wrapper, .pat_index_col1, #header, #footer, .dataTables_wrapper, #h4 {
        display:none;
        }

    .print {
        height: 132.283464567px; 
        width: 264.566929134px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        border-radius:5px;
        page-break-inside:avoid;
    }

    table {
        width: 264.566929134px;
        height: 132.283464567px;
    }

    thead {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:10px;
    }

    tbody {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    tfoot {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:8px;
            background-color:#060;
    }
}
```

I need the table to fit within the parameters specified above. They have to be that big because they need to fit inside special labels.

Is there a way you can put a table within the print statement so that it forces to fit within those 'margins'? Or if there is another way to print HTML so it fits into the specified dimensions, I would be more than willing to look into it.

Comment: 'I need the table to fit within the parameters specified above' - Which ones? You have assigned fixed dimensions to the table. And why do you use `px` for print styles?

Comment: Is the table inside the `.print` element? If so, won't `100%` work?

Comment: @zeroflagL Sorry. The are needs to fit within 'height: 132px; width: 264px;`. And I don't know why I use px. Is there another form of measurement.

Comment: @MrLister Yes, the data is inside a table within `<div class="print"></div>`

Comment: but then I don't understand your question. The table has exactly those dimensions. Is there any problem?

Comment: For printing, the available units are cm, mm, in, pt and pc. See the [W3C definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths). Note that they say if you use pixels, "the physical units might not match their physical measurements."

Comment: @MrLister Thank you for that. I've changed them to mm (the original value).

Comment: @zeroflagL The printout isn't the same. It's printing it slightly off.

Comment: @deathtap I'm afraid you'll have to show us the differences. Scan the printout and put hand drawn red circles around the problem areas.

Comment: @MrLister I figured it out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I intend to do (or try and do), I decided to go with [jsPDF](http://jspdf.com/) as it did what I wanted to do.